streamlit update df interactively
I want to update a df interactively. The user is selecting a row, and then I want the displayed df to "disappear"and only the leftover options should stay visible.
In the original problem, the user will need to make about 30 sections in various rounds.
Here is a minimal example
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


# create df
d = {'Num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     'types': ["A", "A", " A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# add Selection columns
df['selected'] = None


# initialize session state
if 'df' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df = df

# all options
all_options = df['types'].unique().tolist()


# run until 3 options are selected
while len(df[df['selected'].notnull()]) < 3:

    # load session state
    st.session_state.df = df

    # make a list of all selected types
    selected = df['types'][df['selected'].notnull()].unique().tolist()

    # selectable options (list comparisons)
    selectable = [x for x in all_options if x not in selected]

    # only show selectable
    df_select = df[df['types'].isin(selectable)]

    # draw the df and save dict output
    select_dict = st.dataframe(
        df_select,
        use_container_width=True,
        hide_index=True,
        on_select="rerun",
        selection_mode="multi-row",
    )

    # create selected rows
    selected_rows = select_dict.selection.rows

    # crated filtered df from orignal one
    filtered_df = df.iloc[selected_rows]

    # merge the two one an indicator
    df = pd.merge(df, filtered_df, on=['types', 'Num', 'selected'], how='left', indicator='Double')
    # add Selection
    df.loc[df['Double'] == "both", "selected"] = True

    # delete indicator row
    del df['Double']


Now every time the modified df is shown below the original one
